# Three.js TrackBall Controls for Camera behaves weird

Tags: camera, three.js

I been trying to create a simple sphere with the ability of making it spin with the mouse like it happens in [this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_trackballcamera_earth.html) example.

However, when I try to spin the sphere, it does not move as in the previous example but it rather moves in many different directions and extremely accelerated.

I tried several different combinations of settings for the rotate speed but none of them works.

```
    var _container, _camera, _renderer, _scene, _controls;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // init the animation.
        init();

        // animate.
        animate();
    });

    /* Initialize the animation */
    function init() {
        // get the container size.
        _container = $('#animation');
        var height = _container.innerHeight();
        var width = _container.innerWidth();

        // create the renderer and add it to the container.
        _renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ precision: 'highp', antialias: true });
        _renderer.setSize(width, height);
        _container.append(_renderer.domElement);

        // create the scene.
        _scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create the camera and add it to the scene.
        _camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, width / height, 50, 1e7);
        _scene.add(_camera);

        var radius = 50;

        // trackback _controls settings.
        _controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(_camera, _renderer.domElement);
        _controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
        _controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
        _controls.panSpeed = 0.2;
        _controls.noZoom = false;
        _controls.noPan = false;
        _controls.staticMoving = false;
        _controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
        _controls.minDistance = radius * 1.1;
        _controls.maxDistance = radius * 100;
        _controls.keys = [65, 83, 68]; // [ rotateKey, zoomKey, panKey ]

        // create a sphere and add it to the scene.
        var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(45, 30, 20);
        sphereGeo.computeTangents();

        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo,
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true }));
        _scene.add(sphere);
    }

    /* Animates the scene */
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // render the scene.
        render();
    }

    /* Renders the Scene */
    function render() {
        // set the camera to always point to the centre of our scene, i.e. at vector 0, 0, 0
        _camera.lookAt(_scene.position);

        // move the camera in a circle with the pivot point in the centre of this circle
        // so that the pivot point, and focus of the camera is on the centre of our scene.
        var timer = new Date().getTime() * 0.0005;

        _camera.position.x = -Math.floor(Math.cos(timer) * 200);
        _camera.position.y = 50;
        _camera.position.z = Math.floor(Math.sin(timer) * 200);

        _controls.update();

        _renderer.clear();
        _renderer.render(_scene, _camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a TRHEE.Clock instance and use clock.getDelta() instead of your timer. **Attention:** Don't use clock.getDelta() multiple times during your animate process, save the value to a variable.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you very much for answering. I probably did not explain my problem correctly. The thing is the automatic spin of my sphere works fine, the problem comes when I click and drag the sphere and to see the top, bottom or back of it. In the earth example I attached on the link, you can click on the north pole and drag it to see and the planet spins accordingly. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

TrackballControls.js can't deal with these extreme angles. Instead you can use OrbitControls.js which doesn't have the problem as it calculates the rotation differently.